# Spring: Is there any advantage of using spring's lifecyle callback 'destroy-method' over regular finalize() method?

Tags: java, spring

I understand that spring's lifecycle callback `init-method` is useful when you need to do initializations based on the dependencies injected by the IoC framework that can't be done in the regular `contructor` method. But what is the advantage of doing clean ups in the lifecyle callback `destroy-method` over regular `finalize` method?

Comment: finalize in not "regular", and you shouldn't rely on it - it's up to the garbage collector to call it or not, and at the time it chooses - it's bad practice to use it

Comment: @Guillaume: By 'regular' I meant something part of java itself and not spring-specific. But thanks for you reply.

Comment: And by "not regular" I meant this is to be used by the JVM, not by users :) Unless you really know what you're doing. And in this case, don't forget to call super.finalize() in a finally clause.

Comment: @Guillaume: I admit `destroy` is NOT regular :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have provided good answers, but I thought I'd add a piece of explanation on the `finalize()` method.

As a good practice, you should not put application critical code in the `finalize()` method, as there's no guarantee when it will be called (or if it will be called). You can put some last-ditch effort code in there to make sure resources used by a class are freed (files, or communication ports for instance), but you should never rely on this method to do any required cleanup.

Whenever you have a mechanism in place to destroy objects (such as the destroy callback in the Spring framework), you should definitely use it to free resources.

Answer (score 8):

[`finalize`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()) is called by the garbage collector and thus is [not guaranteed to be invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506488/java-finalize-method-call).

Springs [`destroy-method`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-default-init-destroy-methods) or [`@PreDestroy`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations) annotation is called by the container when the spring container is destroying beans, e.g., on application is shutdown, allowing you to deregister services, terminate threads or perform various cleanup code.

Comment: Can't you place the same cleanup code in `finalize()`? Is there any spring framework specific cleanups that must go in the  `destroy-method`?

Comment: Yes you can place the same code in `finalize`, but not always guarantee that it will be run, or run in a timely fashion

Answer (score 5):

The `destroy-method` has more to do with managing bean destruction when the bean's *container* is destroyed. `finalize()` is for the JVM, really, and isn't *directly* tied to Spring's lifecycle management.

IMO Spring-managed beans should prefer `destroy-method` both to keep things communicative (it's more obvious, because it's stated explicitly) and to ensure that destruction happens under more-controlled circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

And finalize is not guaranteed to be called.