# How am I able to call finalize()

Tags: java, protected, finalize

In the following code, I am getting the output Hello. Can anyone explain why compiler is not reporting an error it I am calling a protected function outside the class and inheritance chain.

```
package sampleproject;

public class SampleProject 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Sample s=new Sample();
        s.finalize();
    }
}

class Sample
{
    @Override
    protected void finalize()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are these two classes in the same package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`protected` scope includes the *package*, as well as the class and subclass(es). Both your classes are part of the same package.

I hope you're not intending to call `finalize()`, btw. That should be left to the garbage collector (and not relied on,. either!). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2506525/12960) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

`protected` makes a method visible in the same package

This might help: [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 0):

> **protected** members can only be accessed by members of their own class,
>   that class's subclasses or classes from the same package.

From [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords)

Answer (score 0):

You have a file called `SampleProject.java` inside the package `sampleproject`. SampleProject.java contains two classes defined namely `SampleProject` and `Sample`. So when you compile the file SampleProject.java , you will see `SampleProject.class` and `Sample.class` in the same folder. So they are in same package (because compiler inserts package as `samplepackage` for the `Sample.class`, hence calling the `finalize` method succeeds.