# Finalisers, closing files and streams

Tags: java, effective-java

In Joshua Bloch's book "Effective Java" item 7 second edition he advises to avoid using finally statements particularly for closing files he says "it is a grave error to depend on a finaliser to close files". Two pages later he says that one of the two use cases where it is a legitimate is in the explicit termination method pattern

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
try{
    ///process foo
} finally{
    foo.terminate();
}
```

Classes that have a termination method include FileInputStream and FileOutputStream. So wouldn't that mean closing a file in a finally statement?

1) Is Joshua Bloch's Item 7 contradictory?

2) Is the termination method pattern needed? Can't you write the code above without a finally statement that will have the same effect?

Comment: finalizers != finally

Comment: `InputStream` does not have a terminate method. Maybe you mean a `close()` method from the `Closeable` interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that the author meant that you should use a `finally` block code (this is not a finalizer) in `try-catch` to close/clean your resources instead of relieving on `finalize` method (this is a finalizer).

For more info about finalizers check [When is the finalize() method called in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2506488/1065197)