# Is there any hook provided to register a thread with garbage collection in java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, hook

JVM provides you a hook to register a thread with the shutdown initiation sequence. Once a thread is registered, on every shutdown that thread is run.

Now, is there any such a hook java provide to register a thread with JVM's Garbage collector?

Comment: Hooks are specified points, where the developer can specify methods or callbacks to be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly a hook, but you can use a [WeakReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) to be notified that an object has become eligible to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

There are WeakReferences as already mentioned but there are also [Phantom References](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html)

All of these techniques just allow you to monitor garbage collection on specific objects though.

There is a good description of phantom references here: http://java.dzone.com/articles/finalization-and-phantom

Answer (score 0):

You do have [finalizers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29), but they're not guaranteed to run.

Further discussion about why finalizers may not run in this thread:
[When is the finalize() method called in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506488/java-finalize-method-call)