# Difference between final keyword, finally block and finalized method in java throught one good example

Tags: java, final, finally, finalize

Often these keywords confuse me.

Can any one tell me exactly what the difference between them is?

Comment: Nice explanation here: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.es/2012/11/difference-between-final-finally-and-finalize-java.html

Comment: what is 'finally blog'? Are you referring to finally clause in exception handling context?

Comment: @bigdestroyer , thanks for sharing link.
it will help me to clear my concept.

Comment: `final` means the variable cannot be re-assigned.  It _does not_ mean the object cannot be "modified" (by calling methods on the object such as `ArrayList`).  `finally` is something totally different used in `try-catch` structure.

Comment: @aviad sorry for my bad spelling , i was referring the finally block.

Answer (score 8):

### final keyword

**class**

On a class it means you forbid to have a child class extending yours.

```
public final class finalClass
```

**Attribute/Field**

`final MyObject value = new MyObject()` means you won't be able to modify the instance of the object.

`value = xxxx` won't be allowed, but you still can modify the object itself `value.field = "xxx";`

**Method**
When you use `final` on a method, that means you'll forbid child classes that extends your class to override this method.

```
public final void finalMethod()
```

It can also be used on arguments, that means you don't allow other to modify the instance of the object you give.

```
public void myMethod(final MyObject myObject)
```

The end user won't be able to do `myObject = ...`

---

### Finally block

`finally` block has nothing to do with `final`, it's used when catching Exception to ensure a part of code will be ran, wherever there is an exception or not.

```
try { ...}
catch {} // Optional
finally { // Code that will be ran, exception or not being thrown}
```

[image: Finally in Java]

---

### Finalize method

It's called on every object when it's destroyed (usually garbage collected).

Comment: thanks for answering my question, 
i got understand about the final keyword now.
Still i am confused with finally and finalized method.

Comment: @MitulMaheshwari `finalize` will be automatically called on every object when it's going to be destroyed. There's not much more to say from my knowledge.

Comment: thanks for such good explanation.
i have already make vote up for the answer.

Comment: No problem, take a look at others too since i may not have been complete.

Answer (score 2):

`Final:-` It is used in the following cases:

- If the final keyword is attached to a variable then the variable becomes constant i.e. its value cannot be changed in the program.
- If a method is marked as final then the method cannot be overridden by any other method.
- If a class is marked as final then this class cannot be inherited by any other class.
- If a parameter is marked with final it becomes a read only parameter.

`Finally:-`

If an exception is thrown in try block then the control directly passes to the catch block without executing the lines of code written in the remainder section of the try block. 
    In case of an exception we may need to clean up some objects that we created. If we do the clean-up in try block, they may not be executed in case of an exception. 
    Thus finally block is used which contains the code for clean-up and is always executed after the try ...catch block.

`Finalize:-`

It is a method present in a class which is called before any of its object is reclaimed by the garbage collector. `finalize()` method is used for performing code clean-up before the object is reclaimed by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 1):

The java **Final keyword** can be used in many context.

1. Variable - If you make any variable as final, you cannot change the value of final variable(It will be constant).
2. Method - If you make any method as final, you cannot override it.
3. Class - If you make any class as final, you cannot extend it.  [read more](http://www.javatpoint.com/final-keyword)

**The finally Block**

The `finally` block always executes when the `try` block exits. This ensures that the `finally` block is executed even if an *unexpected exception occurs*. Putting *cleanup code* in a `finally` block is always a good practice, even when no exceptions are anticipated. [read more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)

**finalize method** in java is a *special method* much like main method in java. `finalize()` is called *before Garbage collector* reclaim the Object, its last chance for any object to perform cleanup activity

Main issue with `finalize` method in java is its *not guaranteed by JLS that it will be called by Garbage collector or exactly when it will be called*, for example an object may wait indefinitely after becoming eligible for garbage collection and before its `finalize()` method gets called. similarly even after finalize gets called its not guaranteed it will be immediately collected. [read more](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/03/finalize-method-in-java-tutorial.html)

Comment: @atish_shimpi thanks for sharing, 
but what about other finally and finalized method ?

Answer (score 1):

### final

It is used in the following three cases:

1. If the final keyword is attached to a variable then the variable becomes constant i.e. its value cannot be changed in the program.
2. If a method is marked as final then the method cannot be overridden by any other method.
3. If a class is marked as final then this class cannot be inherited by any other class.

source: http://www.go4expert.com/articles/final-finally-finalize-java-t28061/

### finally

The `finally` block always executes when the try block exits. This ensures that the `finally` block is executed even if an unexpected exception occurs. But `finally` is useful for more than just exception handling — it allows the programmer to avoid having cleanup code accidentally bypassed by a `return`, `continue`, or `break`. Putting cleanup code in a finally block is always a good practice, even when no exceptions are anticipated.

source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

### finalize

The `finalize` method is called when an object is about to get garbage collected. That can be at any time after it has become eligible for garbage collection.

Note that it's entirely possible that an object never gets garbage collected (and thus `finalize` is never called). This can happen when the object never becomes eligible for gc (because it's reachable through the entire lifetime of the JVM) or when no garbage collection actually runs between the time the object become eligible and the time the JVM stops running (this often occurs with simple test programs).

There are ways to tell the JVM to run `finalize` on objects that it wasn't called on yet, but using them isn't a good idea either (the guarantees of that method aren't very strong either).

If you rely on `finalize` for the correct operation of your application, then you're doing something wrong. `finalize` should **only** be used for cleanup of (usually non-Java) resources. And that's *exactly* because the JVM doesn't guarantee that `finalize` is ever called on any object.

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2506509/1048340

---

This is all results of a quick Google search; which you should have done before posting the question :P

Answer (score 1):

The final keyword depends on where you use it:

- `public final class ...`, here you say that this class cannot be a super class (so no one can inherit this).
- `public final String someField`, here you say that the String `someField` cannot be changed (after it has been initialized for the first time of course).
- `public final myMethod() { ... }`, here the method cannot be overriden in a subclass.

A finally block is used to get some code to run irrelevant whether the try catched the exception:

```
try {
    Random rand = new Random();
    if (rand.nextInt(2) == 0) { throw new Exception(); }
    System.out.println("You'll get here 50% of the time (when no exception is thrown)");
catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("This should happen 50% of the time.");
} finally {
    System.out.println("You will ALWAYS get here!");
}
```

The finally method is something like this: `protected void finalize()`, this can be overriden by parent (`@Override`), like this:

```
@Override
protected void finalize() {
    System.out.println("Do something");
}
```

The finalize-method should be run when garbage collection decides to remove the object. However this only happens when there are no references to the object. However it has some serious downsides. I would only use it when I would have some native data stored somewhere that has to be freed. But you'll probably almost never do that.

Hope this helps.