# Delete file from temp folder after uploading in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, temp

I'm using 2.2.3 version of Play Framework, and my snippet for uploading file is as follows:

```
def process = SecuredAction(false, None, parse.temporaryFile) {
request =>

    val uploadedFile = request.body.file

    service.processFile(uploadedFile)    
    ...

 }
```

This parse.temporaryFile parser is polluting my temp folder with the files similar to this one: 
requestBody4950142040693742317asTemporaryFile_1424693062067.zip. I want to get rid of these files from my temp folder. Any suggestion how to prevent them from creation or how to delete them after uploading?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Play's upload but it seems you can do:

```
service.processFile(uploadedFile)
request.body.clean()
Ok("All done!")
```

I'm assuming service.processFile is synchronous here.

Answer (score 1):

@AndreasDuRietz is correct that you can call `request.body.clean()`, which is just an alias to delete the underlying `File`. However, this is not necessary. `TemporaryFile` overrides `finalize`, which will call `clean()` for you when the object is garbage collected.

See the [source](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/a0a8bd5796c746334dac1d88f65cda66975cb6a8/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/Files.scala#L35-40).

Comment: But keep in mind that `finalize` may never be invoked.  [See why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2506509/1059400)

Answer (score 0):

```
                /*delete to-server-temp-folder uploaded file*/
                  request.body.file("Img").foreach {
                    case FilePart(_, _, _, ref, _, _) =>
                      val file = new File(ref.path.toString)
                      if (file.exists()) file.delete()
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Play! 2.7.x

```
    request.body.delete()
```