# Effective Java - Never depend on a finalizer to update critical persistent state

Tags: java, finalizer

Why this should not be done? As finalizers will be called when garbage collection is executed, why can't we add persistent related code here?

Comment: One main reason is finalizers ignore exceptions, so if you get any fatal exceptions while persisting the data, it can be ignored.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506488/when-is-the-finalize-method-called-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says critical(!) persistent data. It is ok to have finalizers who will write away persistent data but it must be ok if this data is not written.

Since it is not ok to be missing critical data, it should not go into a finalizer.

But how can a finalizer not be called when the GC has to collect everything?
Well for once the application could just be terminated forcefully, thus never leaving a chance for the GC to run.

Answer (score 5):

As the book explains

> Not only does the JLS provide no guarantee that finalizers will get
>   executed promptly, it provides no guarantee that they'll get executed
>   at all. It is entirely possible, even likely, that a program
>   terminates without executing finalizers on some objects that are no
>   longer reachable.