# In finalize() method statement written after the call to superclass finalize() method will execute?

Tags: java

In `finalize()` method the statement written after the call to superclass `finalize()` method will execute or not?

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506488/when-is-the-finalize-method-called-in-java

Comment: What happens when you test it? Why wouldn't it execute?

Comment: Unless, of course, an exception is thrown during finalization of the superclass. In that case, as [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()) stated, it just will be ignored.

Comment: ...Why are you using `finalize`?  You're not guaranteed that it will be executed.  Ever.

Comment: @Makoto I believe OP's informed about that, but trying to understand the behavior.

Comment: First try it by your self. Just Don't raise your non-experimented queries.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. An exception might be thrown. But you shouldn't have any code after that anyway. The correct form is:

```
protected void finalize() throws Throwable
{
    try
    {
        // your code here ...
    }
    finally
    {
        super.finalize();
    }
}
```