# How to know before an object is destroyed

Tags: java

Is there a way to know before an java object get destroyed??

For example:

class A{}

I have instantiated it as new A(). Now I would like to know when this object will get destroyed and do some operations before it get destroyed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intention is highly unrecommended. Since it is entirely unpredictable when the gc is running and when this method is actually called.

How ever:

You can override the `finalize()` method of `Object`:

For Details see here: [When is the finalize() method called in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506488/when-is-the-finalize-method-called-in-java)

This method is called if and when the gc determines that a particular object is not referenced any more.

See also: [Oracle JavaDoc for Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way, it is called "object finalization".  Look at the `Object.finalize()` method.  But beware: if that path down you go, only pain will you find.