# How to Ensure Method is called before Object is Destroyed?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I've written a custom logging Class that behaves very similarly to a PrintWriter like System.out or System.err. The main difference is that when `myLogger.printf("Hello World!\n");` is called, the data isn't written directly to the log file, but instead to an internal queue, and this queue only gets flushed to the output file via the `flush();` method. So use of the code looks like this:

```
myLogger.println("Line 1.");
myLogger.println("Line 3.");
myLogger.println("Actually that was Line 2. THIS is Line 3!");
myLogger.flush();
```

Which should give an output that (sort of) looks like this:

```
2016-03-30 15:44:45::389> Line 1.
2016-03-30 15:44:45::390> Line 3.
2016-03-30 15:44:45::395> Actually that was Line 2. THIS is Line 3!
```

However, the problem I have is when users make mistakes. Namely, they forget to call `flush()`, and the data they've written to the logger never gets dumped to the file, and the program closes without ever flushing the data.

I can't flush after every single call, because it would defeat the purpose of writing this class in the first place. And having the system manage automatic flushing would be similarly self-defeating.

My idea was to put a call to `flush()` inside the `finalize()` method of the object, but as I've read from [several other articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506488/when-is-the-finalize-method-called-in-java) on this site, there's no guarantee that `finalize()` will ever be called.

Just for clarity's sake, this is what the `flush()` method looks like:

```
public void flush() {
    open();
    while(!unwrittenLogs.isEmpty()) {
        String line = unwrittenLogs.poll();
        log.print(line);
    }
    close();
}

private void open() {
    if(log == null) {
        try {
            log = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(logFile, true));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.printf("Unable to open Log File.\n%s\n",e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}

private void close() {
    if(log != null) {
        log.close();
        log = null;
    }
}
```

So what is my best option to ensure that the logger is flushed before the program quits?

Comment: There are two things you can do: flush after every X writes, where X is configurable. Also you can [register a shutdown hook](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook-java.lang.Thread-) that calls `flush()` one last time. The shutdown hook won't always be called either, as the VM might just crash.

Comment: There is also a subtle data race in your code: when `flush()` is called, another thread may still be posting messages in your logger, so when `close()` is called, `unwrittenLogs` may still have entries that will be silently dropped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your method into the finalize method, like this:

```
@Override protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // do some crazy stuff here
    super.finalize();
}
```

This is and example for object destruction.

For saving the data before the JVM gets shut down, use shutdown hooks:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        @Override public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // do the other crazy stuff in here
            super.run();
        }
    });
}
```

But both will not be a 100% safe to use.
1) You can close the JVM without all finalizers being run
2) If you kill the JVM process via task manager / kill signal, the shutdown hooks wont be triggered

Comment: How do you mean? They deal with different aspects in the object lifecycle. One deals with GC, the other the sane shutdown of the JVM.

Comment: @WillHartung That is true but if you register a shutdown hook, the object won't be eligible for GC anyway until the VM shuts down. See John Bollinger's answer as to why this is the case.

Comment: throw a weak reference into the mix and that won't be a problem

Answer (score 3):

You've asked two different questions: how to ensure that your loggers' `flush()` method is invoked before that object is *collected*, and how to ensure that it is invoked before the program quits.  As you gathered from your research, the logger might **not** be collected before the program quits, therefore a finalizer cannot guarantee that the method will be called.

If you would be satisfied with the logger being ineligible for GC prior to VM shutdown, then you could register a [shutdown hook](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) with the runtime, that flushes the logger.  Such a hook would need to hold a reference to the logger, and the runtime will hold on to a reference to the hook (an unstarted `Thread`) until it shuts down, so the logger will remain ineligible for GC until the runtime executes its shutdown hooks.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to a flushable writer:

1. use a `TransferQueue<LogItem>` implementation
2. create a separate log writer thread
3. do a `take()` on the queue. [blocking]
4. open log file, optionally do truncation and log rotation as desired at this point
5. write taken item, drain additional items with `poll()` [non-blocking]
6. flush and close log file
7. if(application still running) then goto 3

This approach has several advantages:

- the log thread will suffer the IO and flush costs, not the threads executing your business logic
- it's thread-safe as there is only one writing thread
- log item submission is lock-free as long as the TransferQueue implementation is, such as `LinkedTransferQueue`
- the logger thread will keep the VM alive until logs are written, assuming `thread.setDaemon(false)`, which is the default.