# Java object finalize inside Collection

Tags: java, finalize

I thought Object finalize() is always called before the object is retired. In this test, I observed that when object is added to a collection and collection is cleared, the finalize is not called on the object. It is definitely called on the list. Note, I turned escape analysis off -XX:-DoEscapeAnalysis to prevent optimization. Could somebody explain to me, please?

```
    List<MyClass> list=new ArrayList<>(); 
    MyClass c=new MyClass();
    listM.add(c);

    list.clear();
    list=null;
```

Comment: Please provide a full example. What behavior do you expect out of your object's finalization? Also, are you sure that the variable `c` has gone out of scope? Because at no point in the code that you posted does it go out of scope.

Comment: There's no guarantee `finalize` will *ever* run. Also, why do you think the list's `finalize` is getting called?

Comment: And as @user2357112 stated, it is poor practice to expect `finalize` to ever be called consistently.

Comment: There is no guarantee when finalize will be called other than when the Garbage Collector runs.  This question sums it up well:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506488/when-is-the-finalize-method-called-in-java.  I really don't do anything at all in Java finalize anymore as you have no control over when it happens

Comment: You still have a reference to the object yourself via `c`. Your question therefore makes no sense.

Comment: Oops, EJP - thank you, totally my miss.