# Will un-close resources auto-close by gc in java or other gc-lang? and why

Tags: java, garbage-collection

A resource such as a fileInputStream, was not close. Will it be closed when gc clean it? and why or why not?

Answer (score 1):

Refers to: [When is the finalize() method called in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506488/when-is-the-finalize-method-called-in-java)

`FileInputStream` overrides `Object#finalize`, as seen below:

```
/**
 * Ensures that the <code>close</code> method of this file input stream is
 * called when there are no more references to it.
 *
 * @deprecated The {@code finalize} method has been deprecated.
 *     Subclasses that override {@code finalize} in order to perform cleanup
 *     should be modified to use alternative cleanup mechanisms and
 *     to remove the overriding {@code finalize} method.
 *     When overriding the {@code finalize} method, its implementation must explicitly
 *     ensure that {@code super.finalize()} is invoked as described in {@link Object#finalize}.
 *     See the specification for {@link Object#finalize()} for further
 *     information about migration options.
 *
 * @exception  IOException  if an I/O error occurs.
 * @see        java.io.FileInputStream#close()
 */
@Deprecated(since="9")
protected void finalize() throws IOException {
    if ((fd != null) &&  (fd != FileDescriptor.in)) {
        /* if fd is shared, the references in FileDescriptor
         * will ensure that finalizer is only called when
         * safe to do so. All references using the fd have
         * become unreachable. We can call close()
         */
        close();
    }
}
```

When `FileInputStream#finalize` is called, `FileInputStream#close` will be called with it (under certain conditions).  However, `Object#finalize` has been deprecated in Java 9, so it should **not** be relied upon.  You should always close your streams to prevent memory leaks, even if the underlying garbage collection may handle it for you.