# Is there any destroy method in JavaFX we must call before leaving the page/controller

Tags: javafx, destructor, destroy, finalize

In my JavaFX application, at a specific page I have to initialize (when loading the page) some devices such as iris scanner, fingerprint scanner, cameras etc. Before leaving the page/controller it is necessary to **deinitialize** the devices. There are two buttons in that page. If the user leaves this page by clicking one of these two buttons I can easily deinitialize them. But if the user leaves the page by clicking any menu/sub menu (there are more than 30 menu and sub menu in this application), how can I deinitialize these devices?

There is no destructor in java and I also tried using `finalize` but nothing comes out.

Comment: [mcve] please .. don't understand where exactly you see a problem: are you just not inclined to type those x deinitialize commands or do you see a deeper issue?

Comment: You could add a listener to the [parent property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#parentProperty--) of the page which contains the controls for the devices you wish to de-initialize, and do the work to de-initialize the devices if the parent changes to `null`.

Comment: I had similar issues, but in my case it was a static reference deep inside causing it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot rely only on the `finalize()` method. [An answer to this request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2506514/6538278) seems to show that this method is used by the garbage collector to check data loss references. So you need to destroy objects by-hand in a custom method, then `finalize()` will be automatically applied.

You must create a `deinitialize()` method (**public** or **package-private**, depends on the location of your MenuBar controller) then call it inside your sub-menu item.

Comment: There are more than 30 sub menu and I have to call deinitialize() from all sub menu.
I think it isn't a better  solution. I should looking forward to get the better solution.

Comment: I didn't understand :) You want de-initialization to be done without explicitely calling a method in your actionners, because it would be too much to write on your code.

Comment: De-initialization will be done explicitely but I don't want to call de-initialization from 30 sub menu.
I just want a short cut way.