# are there any methods/hooks to force JVM to run Finalization?

Tags: java, jvm

System.gc() is suggests way to run GC and so does System.runFinalization();

but the use Jmap to do heap dump, it will force to do GC/full GC.
so my question is: are there any tools/methods/hooks just like Jmap heap dump that can be used to force execute runFinalization?

I'd like to describe my situation a little bit more:
my heap size won't decrease after a certain time and when I do a head dump I can see that:

1:       6793014      271720560  java.lang.ref.Finalizer

2:       7251647      232052704  java.util.HashMap$Node

3:       6791349      162992376  XX.WP<--- which has override finalize method

so I assumed that it could be caused by finalize method and I'd like give it a quick verification by force execute runFinalization.

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506488/when-is-the-finalize-method-called-in-java) the finalize method is run when the object is garbage collected. Its not recommended to rely on this method beeing called. What is it that you do in these finalize methods?

Comment: I have one more questions: since System.runFinalization() is of suggestion. I'd like to know what is the evaluation process and under what condition it will decide to do or not to do the execution?

Comment: @second first in finalize method it clean the resource allocated by JNI. second it is the legacy code left to me. I have read the link u mentioned. thanks

Comment: There is no sence in "forcing finalization". Once JVM discovers after GC that a finalizable object is no longer reachable, it automatically pushes the object onto the finalization queue. The queue is then processed by `FinalizerThread`.

Comment: `System.runFinalization()` does not force or suggest or something... it just *waits* until the finalization queue gets empty.

Comment: This is an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Just get rid of the `finalize()` method in the class `XX.WP`, that will solve your actual problem.

Comment: @apangin how did u get this conclusion? did u read JVM code or has some other infos that u can share to me?according to the API doc: Calling this method suggests that the Java Virtual Machine expend effort toward running the finalize methods of objects that have been found to be discarded but whose finalize methods have not yet been run. When control returns from the method call, the Java Virtual Machine has made a best effort to complete all outstanding finalizations.

Comment: @Holger the situation is described clearly: I'd like to verified quickly if finalize method is the culprit and if so, then I can get rid of it. so it is not so-called  XY-problem.

Comment: It is, as relying on finalization is an error in itself, even without heap size problems. Besides that, the presence of `java.lang.ref.Finalizer` in your stats is already enough to indicate the finalization is going on and has an impact, as these objects are only created for instances of classes with a nontrivial finalize method. So what else do you want to verify? Just get rid of them and you have solved at least one problem. At the same time, you'll find out whether it also solves the other problem.